# Не меняется свойство selected

Tags: jquery

назначаю выбранный пункт

```
$("#select-forma [value='val3']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

```html
<select id="select-forma" >
    <option value="val1">Значение1</option>
    <option value="val2">Значение2</option>
    <option value="val3" selected="selected">Значение3</option>

</select>
```

Когда я добавляю атрибут *selected*, активным становиться 3-ий элемент.

Но если я захочу поменять потом, например, на "Значение1", атрибут *selected* так и остается у 3-его.

При

```
$( "#select-forma" ).change(function() {
    console.log($( "#select-forma :selected" ).val());
});
```

возвращается `val3`

Как сделать так, чтобы атрибут *selected* так же переходил от одного option к другому?

Comment: а зачем нужно переносить атрибут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#select-forma").change(function() {
  console.log($("#select-forma").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select-forma" >
  <option value="val1">Значение1</option>
  <option value="val2">Значение2</option>
  <option value="val3" selected>Значение3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: а если selected="selected"

Comment: @des1roer, без разницы.